# Angular Dart custom injection failing in dart2js

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a podo class CarStorage for angular to inject.

```dart
class CarStorage {
  int _carIdCounter = 0;
  ...
```

I wire it in using type:

```dart
module
    ..type(CarForm)
    ..type(CarItemsList)
    ..type(CarStorage)
    ;
```

It works in dartium but fails to load in dart2js. I get the following error:

```dart
Illegal argument(s): No type factory provided for CarStorage! (resolving GarageAppController -> CarStorage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered through some bug reports and guess work you need to add the DI Injectable annotation:

```
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Injectable()
class CarStorage {
  ...
```

edit: Fixed the import.
Do **NOT** use     `import 'package:di/annotations.dart';`  this causes errors

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I had the same problem. AngularDart's documentation really is poor, isn't it?